# How to get live variable updates on a statusbar in C++ with Qt's signals and slots?

Tags: c++, qt, statusbar, signals-slots

I am using a proprietary driver API in my C++ / Qt application. There is an object named "status" which is essentially an integer value, that can be used to monitor errors. A value of 0 indicates all is fine, a negative value is a specific error. I would like to program a statusbar (using Qt's [**QStatusBar**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html)) which will give me live updates with the "status" current value as I execute parts of the code. A simplified example of what I currently have:

*DriverInterfaceClass.h*

```
#ifndef DRIVERINTERFACECLASS_H
#define DRIVERINTERFACECLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include "multicam.h"

class DriverInterfaceClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DriverInterfaceClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~DriverInterfaceClass();

private:
    void setStatus(int value);

private:
    MCSTATUS status;

signals:
    void statusChanged(const QString& status, int timeout);
};

#endif // DRIVERINTERFACECLASS_H
```

*DriverInterfaceClass.cpp*

```
#include "driverinterfaceclass.h"

DriverInterfaceClass::DriverInterfaceClass(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    setStatus(McOpenDriver(NULL));
    status = McSetParamStr(MC_CONFIGURATION, MC_ErrorLog, "error.log");
}

DriverInterfaceClass::~DriverInterfaceClass()
{
    setStatus(McCloseDriver());
}

void DriverInterfaceClass::setStatus(int value)
{
    status = value;
    QString statusStr = QString::number(status);
    emit statusChanged(statusStr, 0);
}
```

*MainWindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "driverinterfaceclass.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    DriverInterfaceClass *driver;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*MainWindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    driver = new DriverInterfaceClass(this);
    connect(driver, &DriverInterfaceClass::statusChanged, ui->statusbar, &QStatusBar::showMessage);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I have a problem figuring out how to update the statusbar with the value of the "status" variable. I am not getting any messages in my statusbar with this code. Perhaps I am missing something in the way I initialize my variable?

Comment: The status should not be set manually. Something, e.g. `DriverInterfaceClass`.should handle it.

Comment: I would actually need the status to be updated regardless of whether the status != value condition is met - I want the statusbar to receive a corret value from several points in my software. What do you mean that the class should handle it?

Comment: Think about it like that - does it make sense to come to me and TELL me how I feel, or is it better to ASK me how I feel.

Comment: In other words, the driver interface is not supposed to have a public set method for the status. Instead the status should be set internally. to the outer world status is a read-only property of `DriverInterfaceClass`.

Comment: That of course makes perfect sense. However, my status variable is somehow not updated with these parameter settings, therefore, I get the value it has been initialized with every time when using the getter method.

Comment: Prepare a [mcve]. Otherwise it is hard to tell where the problem is.

Comment: You expect to have the result of `McSetParamStr` displayed on the status bar, right?

Comment: Yes. the McSetParamStr or McSetParamInt, since I can handle different data types and conversion if I need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225513/discussion-between-szumial-and-scopchanov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

The `statusChanged` signal suffers from an [unperceived existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest#:%7E:text=The%20tree%20will%20make%20a,it%20could%20have%20been%20heard.&text=Since%20sound%20does%20not%20exist,and%20sends%20off%20air%20waves.). In other words, the `driver` object screams - STATUS CHAAAAAAANGED!!!!, but no one hears it. Here is why.

Your code is executed in the following order:

```
driver = new DriverInterfaceClass(this);
```

Then, as part of the constructor:

```
setStatus(McOpenDriver(NULL));
status = McSetParamStr(MC_CONFIGURATION, MC_ErrorLog, "error.log");
```

Only then is the connect statement executed:

```
connect(driver, &DriverInterfaceClass::statusChanged, ui->statusbar, &QStatusBar::showMessage);
```

Obviously, the signal is emited by `setStatus` *BEFORE* it is connected to the slot of `ui->statusbar`.

**Note:** You also set the value of `status` directly, without calling `setStatus`, i.e. `status = McSetParamStr(...`, thus the signal is not emited at all. However, calling setStatus instead would not help, because of the same reason as above.

Moving `connect` before `new` would cause a compiler error, because you cannot connect to something, which does not exist.

### Solution

Do not emit signals from constructors. Do it when an event occurs.

Comment: Thank you @scopchanov ! This is why my example was not working. I have followed your answer and after calling a new method to open the driver outside of the constructor, the statusbar was updated as expected.

Comment: @szumial, You are very welcome! I am glad that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy your invariant "emit signal whenever status is set" you need to use `setStatus(McSetParamInt(... whatever));` method, don't modify `status = xxx;` directly (apart from the body of `setStatus` method). Then just change your setter function a bit to also emit the information about desired message to be displayed on the `QStatusBar`:

```
void DriverInterfaceClass::setStatus(int value)
{
    if (status != value)
    {
        status = value;
        emit statusChanged(myStatusValueToString(status));
    }
}
```

where signal decl should be:

```
signals:
    void statusChanged(const QString& msg);
```

and your `myStatusValueToString` just a simple mapping:

```
QString myStatusValueToString(int status)
{
  if (status == 0) return "OK";
  ... etc ...
}
```

The connection should look like:

```
QObject::connect(driver, &DriverInterfaceClass::statusChanged, statusBar, &QStatusBar::showMessage);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP has already done that and has problems with calling `setStatus`, not its implementation.

Comment: I think at least the first sentence of this answer should be helpful to OP. Don't modify `status` outside of the setter function.

Comment: Yep, honestly the question is not 100% clear to me. I thought that the major issue is OP trying to call `status = McSetParamInt(...);` `status = getStatus();` `setStatus(status)` which is a) redundant, b) not detecting if status changed or not; Let's wait for him to comment.

Comment: I believe my issue is the way this status variable is, or rather isn't updated. I know how to handle the signals and slots and create a connection. This status integer is just never reflected correctly in my statusbar. Perhaps the problem is the way I declared the emitted signal.

Comment: @szumial OK, then you need to edit the question with reproducible example (yeah I know that for Qt it might be a bit more code than normally) of the problem, because for me it works as it should, i.e. QStatusBar is updated whenever status value changes.

Comment: You can check my updated question now. This should be more explanatory. My application is more complex than that, as I am using a stacked widget which renders several UI pages and I am trying to keep the DriverInterfaceClass as little based on Qt as possible. My statusbar is also using a custom widget which takes care of what is displayed on it.